# Запуск плагина jQuery Montage по событию click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сам плагин [jQuery Montage](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/).

Дело в том, что он работает при событии "resize" окна браузера, хотел прикрепить "click" но не сработало.Подскажите как реализовать дополнительное событие для плагина?

Comment: Полноценный ответ дать Вам не могу, так как давно с jq не работал, а с этим плагином и вовсе. Но можете попробовать тригерить resize в обработчике клика. Приблизительно так: `.click(() => {объект к которому подключен плагин}.resize())`

Comment: Он использует this, как я понял.

Comment: `(function(window, $, undefined) {
var $event = $.event,
resizeTimeout;
$event.special.smartresize = {
setup: function() {$(this).bind("resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler)},
 teardown: function() {
 $(this).unbind("resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler)},
 handler: function(event, execAsap) {
 var context = this,
 args = arguments;
 event.type = "smartresize";
 if (resizeTimeout) {
 clearTimeout(resizeTimeout)}
 resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
 $(context).trigger(event.type, args)
 }, execAsap === "execAsap" ? 0 : 50)}};
})(window, jQuery);`

Comment: Уточните чего именно код выше, вашей реализации или плагина?

Comment: Код плагина jQuery Montage

Comment: Да так я и предположил. Вам не нужен код плагина. Вы же где то его инициализируете и подключаете к какому то компоненту в вашем проекте, так? Покажите мне этот код.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109603/discussion-between-spoon-100500-and-vasiliy-rusin).

Comment: Привязка через toggle не помогает, добавляю click через bind:
`function() {
            $(this).bind("click resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler)
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $(this).unbind("click resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler)
        },`
потом через toggle:
`$('#Menu_Icon').click(function(){$container.trigger("click");});
`не работает